# Spinner in a alert.dialog crashes

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog which has a spinner into it:

```
LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.change_bike_state, null);

AlertDialog.Builder changeState = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

changeState.setTitle(bikeName + " " + stateName);
changeState.setView(layout);

String state_data[] = new String[3];

state_data[0]="Alquilada";
state_data[1]="No alquilada";
state_data[2]="Mantenimiento";

Spinner states = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.bike_states);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(activity,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state_data);

states.setAdapter(adapter);

   //positive and negative button

    changeState.show();
```

change_bike_state.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/bike_states"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The spinner is shown, 
[image]

but crashes when clicking.

```
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:257)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-28 12:42:43.114: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: what is the value of context here in arrayAdapter ?

Comment: have u put 
    changeState.create(); before call
    changeState.show();

Comment: tried it, and still crashes!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the activity context in your `Alertdialog` not `activity`. Your dialog is not able to find that in which activity context it should display. So try as below:

> ```
>    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>             View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.view_map, null);
>             AlertDialog.Builder changeState = new AlertDialog.Builder(
>                     context);
>             changeState.setTitle("bikeName" + " " + "stateName");
>                changeState.setView(layout);
>             String state_data[] = new String[3];
>             state_data[0] = "Alquilada";
>             state_data[1] = "No alquilada";
>             state_data[2] = "Mantenimiento";
>             Spinner states = (Spinner) layout
>                     .findViewById(R.id.bike_states);
>             ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,
>                     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state_data);
>             states.setAdapter(adapter);
>             // positive and negative button
>             changeState.show();
> ```

Comment: with this code, teh alert is not shown, it crashes when try to show

Comment: Hey i have updated my answer. Try out with it i have checked and tested it .Its working awesome. Try with my code. You need to pass the context of your activity instead of activity.

Comment: I have the same behaviour, I cant understand!

Comment: I only change context <-> activity because with context crashes ( the alert is not shown)

Answer (score 0):

```
View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.change_bike_state, (ViewGroup)getCurrentFocus());
```

Comment: This throws an exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.change_bike_state, null);

 AlertDialog.Builder changeState = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);

 changeState.setTitle(bikeName + " " + stateName);
 changeState.setView(layout);

 String state_data[] = new String[3];

  state_data[0]="Alquilada";
 state_data[1]="No alquilada";
 state_data[2]="Mantenimiento";

Spinner states = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.bike_states);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(activity,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,     state_data);

 states.setAdapter(adapter);

   //positive and negative button

 AlertDialog alert = changeState.create();

  alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way to inflate `AlertDialog's Layout`

```
  View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.change_bike_state, null, true);
```

instead of

```
  View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.change_bike_state, null);
```